# Can we enable "My Domains" within "Trialforce Source Org"?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mydomain, trialforce

Is there any downside to Enabling "My Domains" within a "Trialforce Source Org"?

Now that My Domains is a necessary function to be enabled for Lightning Components, it is becoming more and more required to be setup in our Trialforce Org, but I am unable to find proper documentation that could answer my query. I'm confused how will it effect New Trials generated from the Trialforce Template from a Trialforce org which has a My Domains setup to "xyz" subdomain?

Because I've noticed that if I don't setup My Domains, then we don't see any Lightning Component of Lightning Component Tab in the Trialforce org (from the Managed Package we need to give Trials for).

Answer (score 1):

New org created from your Trialforce will get a domain name like xyz-1234.
The system will add a random 4 digits number to make your domain unique.
Your customer can open a ticket to get it changed.