# Can a Community be included in a Trialforce template?

Tags: community, trialforce

I think (but am not sure) I could not include a [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) in a [Trialforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/trialforce_conceptual_overview.htm) template a few years ago. One problem was the need for a unique domain name.

We are now using [Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_overview.htm) that are layered on top of Sites. Can a Community be included in a Trialforce template?

**PS** This may be relevant [Can we enable "My Domains" within "Trialforce Source Org"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119729/can-we-enable-my-domains-within-trialforce-source-org)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use case for having a community on trialforce? Is it that you also want to additionally provide say some knowledge articles, support on the trial version of the distribution using communities?

Comment: @JayantDas We have important customer-facing features that use communities and want those to be easily accessed in trials.

Comment: Thanks Keith. While this is not documented anywhere if communities are part of trialforce or not, isn't there an option to reach out to the partner support to get this confirmation? As documented trialforce is available only for **eligible** partners, so would assume to get some response from that channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took Jayant's advice and this https://partners.salesforce.com/0D53A00003jZcp3 is a great link on the subject for anyone who has a Partner Community login.

That thread is quite long and there are quite a few "if this then that" factors (particularly for Sites) but the basic answer is "yes".

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, at least anyone having this issue in future will have a publicly available answer now :)